# Get path from self referencing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with a self referencing table. The depth of the structure can be between 1 and 20

- ID - primary key
- Name - nvarchar(256)
- ParentID - int

Typical data:

| Id | Name | ParentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Folder1 | NULL |
| 2 | Folder2 | 1 |
| 3 | Folder3 | 2 |
| 4 | Folder4 | 3 |

I want to provide an Id and list all "parent" folders

Id=3 : output: **"Folder1\Folder2\Folder3"**

Id=4 : output: **"Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4"**

I looked at [Writing a recursive SQL query on a self-referencing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165398/writing-a-recursive-sql-query-on-a-self-referencing-table) and wrote the following:

```
declare @id int
set @id = 4
;with ItemPath as 
    (
        select a.Id, cast(a.Name as nvarchar(max)) as Name, a.ParentId
        from ParentChild a
        where a.Id = @id --Starting point

        union all

        select a.Id, a.Name  + '/' + parent.Name, a.ParentId
        from ParentChild as a
        inner join ItemPath as parent on parent.ParentId = a.Id 
    )
select * 
from ItemPath
```

but this gives me several rows:

| Id | Name | ParentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Folder4 | 3 |
| 3 | Folder3/Folder4 | 2 |
| 2 | Folder2/Folder3/Folder4 | 1 |
| 1 | **Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4** | null |

I just want the last result

Comment: Pet peeve: [The semicolon (`;`) is a statement terminator](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-the-semicolon-is-a-statement-terminator/) *not* a "beginningator". It goes at the *end* of **all** your statements, not at the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated. Not terminating your statements properly is deprecated, so you should really try to get into the habit of properly terminating your statements now, so that your code doesn't break if the change is ever forced through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are trying to filter values ​​in the wrong place. This should be done not in the CTE, but in the main query, since the CTE is used to build the tree and generate the `Name` value.

Second, you have an error in the CTE in the recursive part when joining the CTE. You have `on parent.ParentId = a.Id` but you need the opposite `on a.ParentId = parent.Id`.

So you query would be like this

```
declare @id int;
set @id = 4;

WITH folder_tree AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        CAST(name AS nvarchar(max)) AS name, 
        parentid 
    FROM folders 
    WHERE parentid IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        f.id,
        CAST(ft.name + '/' + f.name AS nvarchar(max)),
        f.parentid 
    FROM folders f
    JOIN folder_tree ft ON f.parentid = ft.id
)
SELECT * FROM folder_tree
WHERE id = @id
```

Query output

| id | name | parentid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4 | 3 |

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f32ad5f90e4d1d5075ab5f1788a84c7e)

Comment: Just one more challenge for you. What if the top most folder is stored in a separate Table "RootObject". That means that ParentId is never null. "Folder1" with Id=1 is found in this "RootObject" table. Is this possible?

Comment: Then you should start a CTE with `SELECT ... FROM folders WHERE parentid IN (SELECT id FROM rootobject)`. But this DB design is wrong.

Comment: But the Folders does not hold the top most item. It is only stored in the RootObject (only Id and name columns) table. I tried adding `select ID, CAST(name AS nvarchar(max)) AS name, null as parentid FROM rootobjects` as the start of the CTE but then I 4 rows again. And it took 7 seconds to execute.

Comment: I didn't tell that the top most item is stored in `Folders`. But the next level nodes should be related with it, right? So they should have a `parentid`  value those should be equal to `id` in the `RootObject` table. That's why i wrote `WHERE parentid IN (SELECT id FROM rootobject)`. Anyway you are free to create a new question if you are facing any problem.

Comment: You where right :-) I had a typo in my sub select. Thank you  for your help!